# get audit settings file or directory

Tags: windows, audit

I am looking for a report / utility that will tell me what Audit Settings have been set for a particular directory from a command prompt not through the UI.

For example, I set the advanced security settings->auditing for a directory C:\temp so that everyone that creates a file is logged and this is coming out on the security logs.

What I would like to know - is there any way I can run a script to return the audit settings for a selection of directories?

Something like " C:\TEMP" which would return the list from the Directory Audit dialogue and tell me which are set, in the above example it would show "Create File/Write Data   Success, Failure"

i.e. Something similar to running auditpol.exe /get /category:* for example.

Many thanks

Alan